# Angular tutorial, InMemoryWebApiModule throwing 500 internal server error with angular-in-memory-web-api 0.6.0

Tags: angular, angular-in-memory-web-api

InMemoryWebApiModule is working with [downloaded source code](https://angular.io/generated/zips/toh-pt6/toh-pt6.zip) where
`"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.5.0"` But not with`"angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.6.0"`
I have followed the tutorial,to install angular-in-memory-web-api :

```
npm install angular-in-memory-web-api --save
```

And it installed `"angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.6.0"`

Error Message:

`webpack-internal:///./src/app/hero.service.ts:87
  Object
    body:
     error: "Object(...) is not a function"
     __proto__: Object
   headers: HttpHeaders
    lazyInit: ƒ ()
    lazyUpdate: null
   normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
   __proto__: Object
   status: 500statusText: "Internal Server Error"
   url: "api/heroes"
  __proto__: Object
(anonymous) @ webpack-internal:///./src/app/hero.service.ts:87`

Comment: If you would like help to *resolve the issue*, you are going to have to describe the actual issue. *Doesn't work* doesn't tell anything about the problem you are having.

Comment: That's is because `v0.6.0` is meant to be matched against Angular 6, are you using NG6? If not, downgrade to `v0.5.4`  as suggested.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Looks like the [0.6.0 release](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/0.6.0/CHANGELOG.md#0.6.0) of angular-in-memory-web-api has some breaking changes, which are likely out of sync with the versions of angular and rxjs that the tutorial has had you install.

Simplest fix is just to install the 0.5.4 version of angular-in-memory-web-api:

`npm install angular-in-memory-web-api@0.5.4 --save`

Comment: have same issue & it helps me lot

Answer (score 3):

It was indeed an issue with the version of angular-in-memory-web-api.

I force installed v0.5.4 as zyzof suggested and it fixed it immediately! Thanks

```
npm install angular-in-memory-web-api@0.5.4 --save
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and resolved it by uninstalling and installing again. I originally thought it was an authentication issue as I had used firebase to login anonymously with Angular but the tutorials I have used with the in memory-web-api previously were unauthenticated applications.