# angular-in-memory-web-api internal server error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-http, angular2-http, angular-in-memory-web-api

I have reached the latest step in [Angular's Tour-of-Heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial). After using the angular-in-memory-web-api, no data has appeared on my screen. There is no compilation error, but in the browser's console i get this:

[image: image description]

Everything is exactly the same as in the  tutorial. I have not yet found any solution to this, hence why I had to ask it myself.

this is how my package.json looks:

```
{
  "name": "tour-of-heroes",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458598/angular-tutorial-inmemorywebapimodule-throwing-500-internal-server-error-with-a

Answer (score 4):

This is due to changes in version 0.6.0 of angular-in-memory-web-api.
Great way to solve your issue:

```
npm install angular-in-memory-web-api@0.5.4 --save
```

If you download the tutorial full example, the package.json has:

```
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.5.0",
```

so 0.6.0 is out of scope.